# Show mods which specific posts on a page have active flags

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

Right now, when mods are on a page with active flags (on the question or any answer), we get an overlay indicating as much:

[image: Flag overlay]

It's nice to have the obvious indicator there's a flag on that page, but if there are a number of answers on the question, it can be difficult to tell which post is flagged.  When there are multiple flagged posts on one page, it gets even harder.

[image: Flag overlay for multiple flagged posts on one page]

Well, at least we can see there are multiple posts on this page with flags on them, but it can be time-consuming to figure out which flags go with which post, especially as the number of flags and flagged posts grows. When you have 5 flagged posts among 20, not only can it can be quite difficult to figure out which have active flags and which don't, but that overlay can grow quite large and make it difficult to see the posts at all. We can close the overlay, but then we have no information at all about active flags.

Could we please get some way to connect the banner with individual posts (and, perhaps, comments), or (preferably) some indication on (or in the immediate vicinity of) the flagged post as to which post(s) have flags? Perhaps a count on the mod or flag links ("mod (2)"), like suggested edits? Or a different background tint similar to deleted posts?

Comment: Did you try clicking on the word "answered" (or "asked") in the flag pane?  I agree that some indicator right there on the post would be handy (if there are multiple flags I'll often dismiss the flag pane just so I can read the question and answers in peace, then come back to it later).  But there is a way to jump to the flagged posts, at least.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't always work. Say, if it's a lot of flags and the flagged one is short and near the bottom, or if chrome is just acting up...

Comment: Oh, I do most of my moderation in Firefox, so I didn't know about problems with this feature in Chrome.